asyncio CancelledError error in python gRPC AIO client
I am using Python 3.8 and trying to run an example of a gRPC AIO client like the one below:
async def run() -> None:
    global counter
    
    print('run')
    async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel("127.0.0.1:5252") as channel:     
    
        stub = pubsub_pb2_grpc.PubSubServiceStub(channel)
        message=pubsub_pb2.RequestTopicData(node_id="{}".format(int(time.time())),topic_name=topic_name)
        timer=time.time()
        while counter <loop:
            
            try:
                
                responses1 =await request(stub,message)
                tsk1=asyncio.create_task(responsesHandler(responses1))
                await tsk1
                
            except Exception as e:
                raise e
            
    #print("Greeter client received: " + response.message)
if __name__=="__main__":
    global timer,writeBuff,ntp,counter,L0,fp
    counter=0
    asyncio.run(run())

The code just worked a few minutes ago but suddenly the following exception popped up.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\grpc_client_AIOTest.py", line 123, in <module>
    asyncio.run(run())
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError

Any suggestions?
